# How is the PhDs' (in Logics in Math) employment rate?

Tags: mathematics, professorship, university

I am an undergraduate student who is majored in Math now. I plan to continue my phD degree in Logics in Math. My ultimate job plan is to be professor (I know instructor first). So I really want to learn the employment of PhDs in this major.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean?  The proportion of logic PhDs who become professors?  I don't think such data is available, but you can try looking to see where the students of professors you're interest in working with went.

Comment: 100% of university professors in this area are employed.

Comment: The NSF appears to have produced quite a comprehensive report on this topic, although it only considers 2015 graduates, which is perhaps slightly too recent to indicate long-term success, given the number of years one may expect to spend in postdoc positions without ever actually gaining a faculty position. https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2017/nsf17306/static/report/nsf17306.pdf#page12

Comment: I have a Ph.D. that you could think of as a Ph.D. in Logics in Math. Turns out Computer Science has much more money, jobs, positions, and supports than Math., so, depending on the precise field, you could very well brand yourself as a "Logics in CS" professor, and have access to the CS job market, which is better. For a better picture, look at http://cra.org/resources/taulbee-survey/ (In some cases, you can skip the instructor part, if you get post-doc position and then assistant prof.)

Comment: Again, which country are you from/hope to get a job in?! Otherwise, your question is too broad. If it's **France** for instance I think they have quite a lot of people working in logic and related area.

Comment: @dendodge, NSF, is for which country? The OP didn't specify where he/she is from.

Comment: @Dilworth That's US data, simply because it was the first Google result and I took a punt on it being the most relevant to people here (but not myself!).

Comment: "Logics in Math" isn't something that someone in the United States is likely to say (the plural sounds slightly awkward and "mathematical logic" would be more common). To me that usage sounds more like England (where "maths" with the plural is common). Just a guess of course, since OP hasn't specified in their profile.

Answer (score 3):

For mathematics in the US, the American Mathematical Society collects a great deal of data (about employment among many other things) in their [Annual Survey of the Mathematical Sciences](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/annual-survey).

With respect to your specific question, unfortunately they lump logic together with discrete mathematics, combinatorics, and computer science; presumably logic alone would have too few data points to be very informative.  (The inclusion of computer science here doesn't mean the AMS thinks that computer science is one small subfield of mathematics.  That refers, I think, only to people working on theoretical computer science who received their degrees in departments of mathematics.)

[This pdf](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/2015ND-TableE4.pdf) has the table that most directly addresses your question, for 2014-15 doctoral recipients.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "math" you will need to employ one of the first lessons that I believe is fundamental to the discipline: defining. With this, then you can start to build and focus in on your topic of choice: employment rates.

With this said, your best bet (if in the US) is to take a look at the [Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/math/mathematicians.htm#tab-8). In this case, the search parameters are for mathematicians, which loosely covers your search criteria. If you wanted to narrow down your career field, you can select a specific type to consider your aspirations and potential career given that different fields might have differing degree requirements (bachelors, masters, Phd etc.)